# At what point does this answer *not* answer the question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086837/438992 (10k+)

The question is (redux) "Is there an advantage/difference" but it's a simple shortcut method, and the says so explicitly. Few of the other answers offer significantly more information, except for Stefan's.

At least partially I suspect it's some intra-user hostility as I often need to correct the original commenter's answers, but I doubt that's all of it. So I want to know how it isn't an answer.

(And, curiously, *after* the question was deleted, it got another downvote--AFAICT that means someone w/ an ability to undelete a question undeleted it, downvoted it, and re-deleted it?!)

Comment: Relevant? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98959/rtfm-like-answers-flag-them-or-allow-them

Comment: Doesn't that comment mean it appeared in the Low Quality queue? It looks like you just got "punished" for posting a really short answer...

Comment: For reference: [the review item](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1949172)

Comment: @MikeB Possibly, and perhaps I should have added a link, but I included the relevant info from the FM, as in "it's a shortcut method".

Comment: I would expect a better answer from a 67k+ user actually

Comment: I've seen shorter answers, but not by much

Comment: @juergend There's nothing else to say (other than what Stefan said), it's a shortcut method. Rosinante's answer is a better wording, but substantively the same.

Comment: I see my name on this review but do not remember the exact post. I suspect I recommended deletion because I thought it should have been a comment and there is no way to convert it within the queue.

Comment: +1. Looks like I'm in the minority agreeing with you that qualifies as a valid answer. To be honest, I thought it was a poor answer because it didn't really address what the poster wanted to know (he already knew they seemed to work identically, he wanted to know what the actual difference was), and the answer didn't provide a link or even a direct quote from the docs supporting the assertion. So while I think the answer had a lot of room for improvement, I still think it was definitely a real answer.

Comment: If it has been undeleted, downvoted and the redeleted, you should at least see the undelete and delete events in the revision history, shouldn't you?

Comment: @Bart I don't know; it's unclear to me how else it could have been downvoted after it was deleted... It was deleted 21 hrs ago, and got a downvote 9 hours ago.

Comment: @DaveNewton No clue. Especially with that much time between deletion and downvoting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to me that your answer is too terse to qualify. 'The docs'? The docs of what? I know you mean jQuery, but to the google-landing reader, it's potentially opaque. A slightly more verbose formulation ("They do exactly the same thing, one is a notational shortcut for the other, see the jQuery doc") would pass in my book. Not that I'm one of the reviewers here.

Answer (score 3):

Since it was my question, I would say that my only gripe with your answer was that I was interested in the theoretical, not the practical differences, and why people would have a preference. I stated in the question that I knew both methods worked, so while I didn't necessarily agree that yours wasn't a valid answer, it wasn't overly helpful in understanding the observed existence of a preference.

And that was kind of the heart of the question, so telling me they both work, and overlooking the fact that the shortcut sets certain defaults and prevents using certain options, your answer missed the question.

But I'm the newb, so I don't know if that's a fair criteria to say that it's *not* an answer.

Comment: Newbness isn't a criteria for having an opinion. I think Stefan's answer is really the only one that says anything different than mine in a meaningful way, and it's something that I didn't think about when I answered. I'd add that "opinion" parts of questions don't really fall under the SO purview, though, in general.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to answer "Too terse", but that was too terse.