# Flag / close option "what have you tried?" / "plz send me teh codes" questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, question-quality

Regarding [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments)

What is the correct action to take when you encounter [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428709/list-directories-on-a-nexus-server/9428850#comment11922268_9428850) of [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172121/serial-port-reading-junk-data#comment11538830_9172121) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427896/simple-way-to-capture-a-webpage-screenshot-using-python) that sound like the *OP has some genuine problem* but does not really tell enough of it to get any useful answers.

Should one:

1. just vote to close with `not a real question`
2. downvote and comment with link to http://whathaveyoutried.com
3. or hould there be a new option ("reject")? that would essentially "return the question to sender" - which would essentially do the same as "close" - but send the OP a message like *Your question is not a question that can be answered, please add **more information**, such as **sample code** or more details of the nature of the problem* and once the question is edited by the OP it would be automatically reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there isn't enough information to answer the question: vote to close as “not a real question”, because the question is *incomplete* and *vague*. Example: [your serial port example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172121/serial-port-reading-junk-data), [your directory list example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428709/list-directories-on-a-nexus-server).

If it's clear what topic the question is about but it's impossible to tell precisely what the asker's problem is: vote to close as “not a real question”, because the question is *overly broad* and *vague*.

Note that not all questions on Stack Overflow need contain code. “What have you tried?” is an appropriate comment if the question is something like “How do I do <complex task>”. There are legitimate questions that don't contain code, but are requests for a library or algorithm. [Your screenshot example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427896/simple-way-to-capture-a-webpage-screenshot-using-python) is a borderline case, it does lack some information about the asker's requirements, but it's possible to provide general information (it's a massive duplicate, but that's another matter).