# What to do if someone asks you to post code for an answer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, etiquette

The type of question I am talking about is when someone is clearly after code instead of trying to understand the problem themselves. I had a question where, I think, I have answered in enough detail with some code snippets and I keep getting the person asking me to post my full code. What is the protocol if you know the person is simply after the whole source code. I am relatively new here so I don't want to sound mean as I am still in the learning stage of programming myself, but I have seen some answers where people ignore questions when it says, "please post your code", is this the right thing to do?

For the question I answered I was close to posting the source code, as I'm sure there are times I would like the same(!), but I thought other users may complain.  In the end the question actually got closed but other users.

Comment: related: [Is it OK to leave “What have you tried?” comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all the question is asking for is code, I tend to comment asking the OP provide examples of their source and explain where they are stuck. I also explain that on SO we expect some effort to be shown before we answer. If the OP is unresponsive, or the response is completely unrelated to what I have asked for, I will end up downvoting and voting to close as NARQ.

If you answer and believe your answer is detailed enough without code, you are free to ignore such requests or comment back to the OP explaining that you have given enough detail - ask them what exactly where they are stuck...

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to answer.

Just click away and find another better question to spend your precious time answering.

If it's a really bad question then vote it down and/or vote to close - but that's optional. However, if the OP has written:

> Please post your code

then I wouldn't answer as a matter of principle and would probably down-vote and vote to close.