# Better way to frame "which is better" and "which is the best" type questions?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to frame "which is better" and "which is the best" type questions so that they are not tagged as non-constructive, overly broad, or inviting nothing but opinion?

Comment: Related reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/212780

Answer (score 5):

Avoid making your question a comparison question.  Insead of asking `What's the best way to X` or `Which method is better`, Try asking  `"how do I X?"` or even, `"I'm trying to do X, I've looked at both Y and Z and they seem fairly equivalent - is there any reason to use one over the other?"`

For more discussion on this, see: [Gorilla vs Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: "Is there any reason to use one or the other" dives into opinion and gets back into a 'which is best'.  I recommend @TimPost's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204462/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker that part was actually edited in by shog9