# Why is the link to the question about SO not being a recommendation engine closed?

Tags: support, policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is)
>   [What Happened to “What Stack Overflow is Not”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138116/what-happened-to-what-stack-overflow-is-not)

Recently one of my SO questions was closed because it was said to be asking for a recommendation. The first comment with 2 upvotes said "Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine."

Doing some googling of the phrase, I found only [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562) to the purported ST Meta policy "Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine."

However, the page presently displays this message: `This question was removed from Meta Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the FAQ for possible explanations why a question might be removed.`

Am I looking at the wrong link? Why has it been closed? Is the policy still being debated? Was the debate too contentious and the question removed on account of this?

Comment: See [Stack Overflow Is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is).

Comment: The big grey box tells you why your question was closed. Comments (like this one) only express the opinion of a singe user. Also you're confusing closed and deleted.