# What is wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

What is the problem with [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481241/)? I got 2 downvotes already but no explanation as to why. If my question belongs elsewhere, or if the answer is "no", why won't people just tell me?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad question for Stack Overflow - it is asking for resources.

Resource questions are considered not constructive.

In general, questions that ask people for opinions (and people will recommend different resources depending on their opinion of them) are not good questions for Stack Overflow.

Answers are expected to be definitive, which such a question makes impossible.

You may find more detail [in this question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138252/why-was-this-question-asking-for-a-library-recommendation-closed-as-not-construc).

Comment: But there are plenty of questions where a user asks how to do something specific and the best answer is 2 sentances long and links to a library which "solves it all". Whats with that?

Comment: @user1274649 - The question has a definitive answer. It is not asking for "what library will solve my problem"? It is a "here is my problem, what I have done to solve it. This is not working - what can I do?". Do you see the difference?

Comment: So if I reworded my question to "How can I use JavaScript to connect to Multiple Third Party OAuth2 protocols?" Or is it just an impossible question to ask?

Comment: @user1274649 - Well, provided you explain what you have tried already and why that didn't work for you. I suggest reading [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

A question asking for which library/framework to use has exactly the same problems as shopping questions.  Shopping questions are considered "Not constructive" as is [described in this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: But there are plenty of questions where a user asks how to do something specific and the best answer is 2 sentances long and links to a library which "solves it all". Whats with that?

Comment: @user1274649 Answers that contain only links aren't considered good either.

Comment: @user1274649 I don't see the contradiction.  You shouldn't ask specifically for a library and exclude all other solutions, but it's perfectly acceptable to propose using a library as an answer to the question.  (Although, as Mike B has indicated, it needs to be done properly and not just be a link.)  The primary difference here is that other types of answers aren't excluded.