# Can someone repost the raw text of WSOiN onto pastebin or something?

Tags: discussion

I would like to add to [the discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is) on the removal of What Stackoverflow Is Not.  I have lots of examples that I think illustrate how feedback on questions have gotten demonstrably worse without this resource, but I find I cannot articulate this point of view without concrete examples that were housed on that page.

Would it be possible for a 10k person to either post the raw text of that question into pastebin, or perhaps email it to me?  I understand we don't want people to link to it, and that's not what I'm about.  But I feel without being able to even look at it, it prevents us from having a rational discussion on its merits (or lack there of).

Comment: If it had been deleted like two hours later it would be on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did a quick and dirty "Save as page" in Chrome:

- Page 1 http://pgaiser.net/stuff/wsoin.zip
- Page 2 http://pgaiser.net/stuff/wsoin2.zip

I will probably not keep them around forever, so grab them while they're hot.

Comment: It's weird looking at something through someone else's user...

Comment: @Lix heh! True. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags, thanks again!