# stuckoverhelp/stuckoverflaw

Tags: discussion, help

I just ran into this site (http://stuck.include-once.org/) via comment on the main site [via this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954018/calling-clr-stored-procedure). I know its not a SE site, it just seems bad taste

Are we now encouraging 3rd party sites to hold the FAQ and not meta? I sure hope not. I know we have a couple like Jon Skeet's "How to Ask" and the other "What have you tried?". Lifting the design just really is jarring for end users.

I did flag the comment, because that's my gut feeling that that shouldn't happen.

**Aside:** If this I'm correct can we blacklist it like LMGTFY?

Comment: Ah, it seems this particular user is using his site for a sort of "What Stack Overflow is Not" in his comments. This is his own work though, nothing related to SO itself.

Comment: The comment was triggered because the OP reedited his question to include **Thanks in advance** because somebody removed his **Thank you.**. A direct link to the relevant Meta post would have been better though.

Comment: Sounds like a bad joke to me. Unofficial and risky, such comments should be flagged and removed.

Comment: FWIW, I have pointed the user making the comments (not the site owner apparently, he told me) to this Meta discussion.

Comment: Yep, removed all the comments I made. Considering stackexchange is community driven, it's sometimes very, very hard to keep up with all the relevant "directives" and what not. =)

Comment: @J.Steen You have *no* idea.

Comment: @J.Steen The comments themselves were not all that bad. But it would be far better if you could link to a more or less authoritative resource (FAQ, Meta, etc.) rather than a 3rd party site. Not always easy, but far better.

Comment: @Bart Yup yup. If I intend to do more light-weight moderating, I really should have some more research beneath my belt! =)

Comment: @downvoter - why the downvote?

Comment: I'm another downvoter (can't speak for the first one). Downvoting on meta = disagreement with general post, rather than suggesting that it lacked research. I don't quite understand the purpose of the site you link to, but such is the nature of Stack Overflow commanding a wide international audience. AFAICT the site is doing no harm, so leave him to it. It's not remotely at risk of 'passing off', imo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely not part of the SE family.  Just someone who appears to have too much time on their hands. Maybe it exists to get around the whole ["What Stack Overflow Is Not" controversy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted?lq=1)?

Since we have pretty clear guidance to delete such comments:

> If you see this practice (comments that link without bothering to explain why or relate it to the specific post) happening with other links (for instance, http://whathaveyoutried.com), please flag them.

I will do just that.

Leaving a comment for the OP should be done to clarify the question or to help the user understand 'why' things happen.

**Bad**:

> [Phrases to avoid](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help4) include "Sir", "Thanks in advance", "ASAP" and even a bland "Help me" deimpresses people. =)

**Good**:

> You usually get better answers and more upvotes if you take the time to put effort into making your question look professional.  Sometimes people react adversely to 'Thanks in Advance'.  Since I know you want people to upvote your post, I'm letting you know so you can get more reputation.  The "Thanks in advance" also detracts from the visual display of the question. Don't worry, we know you're thanking us for answering, but really, we're doing it for the reputation (just kidding).

Comment: yea i know its a 3rd party, i just don't feel that its an appropriate way to handle it.

Comment: @DanielA.White Neither do I. I think because the target site doesn't make it clear that it's *not* part of the SE family and it took the design, it's easy for a naive user to think otherwise.  Personally, I don't feel any remorse about deleting such comments; but I'd rather not act until there's clear community consensus on the matter.  We do link to Jon Skeet's "How to Ask a question" link, and that certainly isn't official (though it has since been adopted).  This just feels ... *bad*. Maybe it's because of the tone and the copy used ("Lazy asses").

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Actually Jon's blog post is linked to in the ["How to Ask" page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). While that doesn't make it official, it certainly makes it officially endorsed That page is only editable by SE).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker i think someone might want to contact the site owner and get the design at least changed so if it exists, it should minimize the confusion.

Comment: @YannisRizos Yes, but there was time when that *wasn't* the case  (I'm old, I admit it). IIRC it was only a few weeks, but there was some lag there.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The user even identifies himself on the [bottom link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario#summon-me-on-any-question) of that site. (the one that says _"y u no send feedback"_)

Answer (score 3):

Their [about page](http://stuck.include-once.org/about) seems to state the site's objectives -

> STUCK is intended as evil support tool. It's just a list of comment
>   templates actually. And it's the editing backend for the small
>   quickcomments userscript. Also pretty simplistic.

Answer (score 3):

[mario](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148103/mario) claims ownership of the site in his Meta profile. [Another page](http://milki.include-once.org/blog/) on the same domain links to his SO profile, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868864/php-code-for-api-not-working#comment17420327_12868864) is an example of him linking to the site in a comment.

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824436/i-want-to-add-a-referral-link-to-the-url-using-preg-replace#comment17347905_12824436).

Comment: Definitely him. His profile is linked in the site's footer, "y u no send feedback"