# What is Stack Exchange not good for?

Tags: discussion

The Stack Exchange Network contains [a lot of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and it works especially well -- particularly when used in combination with a search engine -- for answering one-off technical questions.  But what is Stack Exchange *not* good for?

For instance, it doesn't seem to provide "paths" through existing questions and answers that people could use to learn a subject from scratch, although this might be a good idea!  It doesn't seem to want to be an encyclopedia (or does it?).

Indeed, it seems to "do one thing and do it well", which is of course a great model for success on the internet!  Are there plans to expand the interaction model, or are the limitations seen as good and healthy ones?

Comment: I don't think we want to be an encyclopedia. Stack exchange is for specific questions, not a resource to learn from scratch. That's wikibooks.

Comment: Actually, the [Scala tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) is a shining example of such a path, but unfortunately it's rather rare to see questions assembled like that.

Comment: If you're not careful, this question [might get deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted).

Comment: @TimPost I think that is a pretty good example of why the Q&A engine just doesn't support path based learning. That wiki obviously took a lot of effort, and I'm not trying to discredit that, but as a tutorial it comes across as extremely piecemeal and disjointed. Unless you know Scala already, it is very difficult to glean useful information from that tutorial.

Comment: @BenLee This isn't asking for a list of undesirable things people do on Stack Overflow, really a different question altogether.

Comment: My comment was kind of tongue-in-cheek :). I just wanted to point out a related question.

Comment: Okay, I promise no more dry humor from me in this thread, I can't seem to pull it off.

Comment: For future reference, [you totally can get pizza at a chinese place](http://fongspizza.com/).

Comment: @BenLee: I slow clapped for you; don't worry, some of us appreciate dry wit.

Comment: @BenLee: the related post is indeed useful: the part that seems most relevant to me is [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137845/212297), where casperOne says "we've dealt with institutionalized rudeness in the past through technology."  I'm inquiring about gaps in the technology, and whether they are there on purpose, or simply haven't been added yet.  Craigslist would have been a wonderful point of comparison.  It doesn't try to do too much, and that contributes to its success.

Comment: possible duplicate of **[What Stack Overflow is Not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not)**

Comment: I guess the "Closed as not constructive" comment below sort of sums it up :)

Answer (score 19):

Stack Exchange is pretty bad at:

- Opening cans
- Sharing feelings
- Finding you a date on Feb. 14th
- Cracking walnuts
- Fracking
- Treating your addiction to chemical solvents
- Weaving carpets
- Listening quietly to your problems without offering solutions because, y'know, you just wanna vent
- Predicting the future
- Finding that thing you just had and must have set down somewhere but can't seem to recall where
- Telling you it's gonna be ok
- Shoveling snow

Stack Exchange shines at allowing folks who know how to do things to explain how those things should be done to folks who need to do them. Other stuff... Well, [we're experimenting a bit](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation).

Comment: "Finding that thing you just had and must have set down somewhere but can't seem to recall where" — rephrase it to mean "stories I read 80 years ago and can't seem to remember", you've made it on-topic for Scifi!

Comment: Disagree with #2 and #6.

Comment: I should note that I *have* successfully used Stack Exchange to open bottles, so #1 is not as bad as it might seem.

Comment: Admit it: SE is good for everything including things it isn't.

Comment: SE never hugs you back :(

Comment: @Asad: It does poke you with a pointy stick though.

Comment: What is so special about February 14th?? It's just another [Thursday](http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/48103_419756081444726_352566873_n.jpg) for me.

Comment: FWIW, the spirit of my question was more about the "platform-" than the "content".  It makes a great deal of sense to me that the platform can be used to do Q&A related to cultural topics.  Maybe the question should have been the more open "what is Q&A not good for?"

Comment: @JoeCorneli There are any number of non Q&A activities that a Q&A platform is not good for. If you were to propose a specific extension to the scope of the site it would be easier to evaluate.

Comment: My question could be rephrased: are there specific things that SE does not want to be?  Proposing those as extensions would be kinda silly!

Comment: @l46kok, February 14 is Valentine's Day in the United States

Comment: It's also good at [encouraging you to create programming languages that will never be used for writing real-life apps](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6918/53917).