# Are there migration bots on SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

I recently asked [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/710836/how-to-submit-iis-created-csr-to-startssl-certificate-provider) on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). In less than a minute, the question got migrated to [Server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/710836/how-to-submit-iis-created-csr-to-startssl-certificate-provider).

The process seems impressive. I'm suspicious that it is done by a [bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261172/present-and-future-of-bots-on-stack-exchange).

If yes, what is the logic behind migratable questions?

`tags`, `text pattern`?

**My question is about logic about such automations**

Comment: I really have to say *kudos* to that mod! Migration in a minute?!

Comment: Don't fundamentally change your question; post a new question.

Comment: Roger that AI E. My mistake!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As can be seen from [the revisions](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/95921/revisions), it was migrated by a mod, [schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder), and not a bot.

Comment: +1 That's impressive, however my question is about the **logic** (;  Say, if I want to automate migration on SE, how will do it?

Comment: @xameeramir If you want to create a proposal for automatic migration you can propose whatever you want in a feature request, and it will be evaluated by the community.

Comment: @xameeramir but I suggest thinking a lot about it before you write a feature-request. Meta is weird ([in a sense](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html)). Some feature requests are surprisingly popular, while others are unpopular. The more thought-into and researched your request is, the more likely you'll get your message across and your idea implemented.