# Converting 'Is Stack Overflow a forum' Q&A into Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki, ownership

There is a Meta SE Q&A that I would like to be able to cite quite frequently:

[Is Stack Overflow a forum?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)

and I would cite it frequently if it were titled something like `Are Stack Exchange (including Stack Overflow) sites forums?

I've attempted to engage the asker of that question to have them generalize it themselves, and they have been resistant to doing so.

I have also flagged it twice to try and have it converted to Community Wiki but even though both flags have been deemed helpful (see below) the title and focus on the question remains as Stack Overflow rather than the Stack Exchange network.

[image]

Is there a policy/protocol that can be linked to as evidence that the user's choice in post content must overrule what appears to be community sentiment, in a case like this?

Comment: Community Wiki isn't going to stop the original asker from forging on with their own agenda by rollbacking every improvement

Comment: @random I suspect that you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately community wiki status kind of depends on whether this question would actually be a good fit as a FAQ. Considering the large amount of discussion and vastly different answers, I'd say it's probably not well-suited to be a full FAQ, and thus community wiki-izing it would be a bit inappropriate.

A full FAQ requires a definitive answer - one single "this is how it is" type of answer that can't be argued anymore. I don't believe we're going to achieve that here. We do throw around the "Stack Exchange is not a forum" thing quite a bit, but that's just to make people think in a different light. It is *part* forum, at least according to [that chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHX9P.png) we throw around just as often.

The problem stems from the fact that the word "forum" can be defined in many ways, and any answers to that question will be inherently subjective because they first have to define the word, and every one will probably define it differently. We already give users a [tour page](/tour) which explains *what we are* - we don't really need a FAQ explaining [what we're not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted). I think it's best left as a normal Q&A pair, whatever content ends up being in it.

---

As far as a "policy" on user's choice - the author of the post is given a lot more say-so on what the content of their post will be. But if the community at large has decided that it should be something else or, in this case, more generalized, then no, they do not *always* have final say over the post. We can and will lock the question if they refuse to leave it in an altered state.

Comment: Your logic on non-CW for this makes sense.  Very similar altered states have been proposed by the following users and rolled back by the asker: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166899/madara-uchiha, me and then http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245360/patrick-hofman Perhaps the next to try should be someone with a diamond on this site :-)