# Creation of an FPC (Frequently Posted Comments)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, comments, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments)

Following [the deletion of "What Stack Overflow is not" (WSOIN)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is) I felt like I would somewhat miss it as it served a purpose, although I agree probably not in the right way.

I think the main benefit of that post was to make it easier to educate people by not having to re-write the same comment over and over.

Building up on the ideas in [this discussion about how WSOIN could be improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134986/how-can-the-what-stack-overflow-is-not-post-be-improved) I suggest the creation of an FPC (Frequently Posted Comments) that could be used as a reference and would unify such comments in an educative and constructive way.

As an example, the [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is) concept is very useful and a good comment when somebody posts a piece of code "that does not work" but the reason for the problem is not in the code that has been posted.

So I can suggest the following FPC :

---

**SSCCE**

> Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Copy/Paste:

`Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.`

Comment: @BenBrocka The idea is similar although what I propose is probably more focused.

Comment: Commenting on accept rate really isn't encouraged.  These comments are off-topic to the question being asked.  They get flagged and deleted often.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Maybe not the best example, but I thought a [consensus had been reached on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate?lq=1) recommending to politely inform new users what the accept rate is - quote: "On the other hand, for users who don't know about the 'acceptance rate' they will require someone to tell them about it."

Comment: @assylias Two sentences later in the same post: "NO, it is not appropriate to change your behaviour because of some user's acceptance rate.  This includes commenting on it."  These comments really are noise, particularly after the user has already worked on their accept rate.  I'd rather see a [system message that notifies users with low accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71334/1288).  That way it's not a distraction for everyone else who reads the post.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm kind of baffled as to why the system shows us a user's accept rate if it's not acceptable to actually look at it or use it in any way

Comment: @BilltheLizard Since my proposal had nothing to do with accept rates per se I have provided a different and hopefully less controversial example.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek "...not appropriate to change your behaviour..." is a little bit strong.  I'm really only concerned with commenting on accept rate.  If users choose not to answer people with low accept rates, that's their prerogative.

Comment: @assylias Thanks!  See how off-topic comments distract from a post?  ;)

Comment: I was personally not really in favor of the deletion of WSOIN, but how is this any different? If we see the exact same message plastered below questions over and over again, would that not lead to similar objections?

Comment: Yes, lets put them all in one place so that Shog9 can delete the post when they become popular.

Comment: @Won't why, what happened? Was something deleted recently?

Comment: `What Stack Overflow is not` is gone? WTF??????

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags The idea is to rebuild something similar to WSOIN in a more positive and educative manner. I agree that this is linked to your post but maybe more general in the sense that it is not meant to address language-specific frequent comments for example.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags: YES!  Feel the rage build inside you!

Comment: @assylias: "more positive and educative manner."  Ugh, somebody hand me a gucci vomit bag.