# Are deleted posts shown in badge-related lists?

Tags: support, badges, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

There are several badges which are awarded for a specific post. For this type of badges you can also see the posts for which they have been awarded. I mean badges like [enlightened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened), [guru](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/guru), 
[populist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/populist),
[reversal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal),
[nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer)/[good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer)/[great](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) answer,
[nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question)/[good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question)/[great](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/great-question) question,
[popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question)/[notable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/notable-question)/[famous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) question,
[investor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/investor),
[promoter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/promoter),
[scholar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/10/scholar),
[student](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/2/student), 
[tumbleweed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed), 
[revival](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/revival), 
[necromancer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer), 
[editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor), 
[excavator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/158/excavator), 
[organizer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/5/organizer), 
[announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer)/[booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster)/[publicits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist), etc. You can see list of all posts where the badge was awarded and also a list of posts where the badge was awarded to a specific user.

I wonder what happens if a post for which the badge was awarded is deleted?

- Will the link to the post still be displayed there or not?
- Does this depend on the fact whether the badge was awarded to me or to another user?
- Does this depend on the fact whether I am the owner of the pots?
- Does this depend on the fact whether I have privilege to [view deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)?

---

I have seen that there are some lists of posts which contain the post even after it was deleted. One example is [favorites tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites). If you favorited a question, you can still see it there even after it was deleted.

There are also badges which are specifically related to deleted posts, such as [disciplined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/disciplined) and [peer pressure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/peer-pressure). I suppose that for those badges the posts are not shown - not even to the post owner. (At least that's what I see in my profile on one site where I have disciplined badge.)

---

A few experiments I have done:

- I can see the link to the post for which [this good question badge was awarded](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=60889). The post is deleted. It is on the site where I have enough reputation to see deleted posts.
- On this site I was able to find several posts mentioning the (now deleted) post [What StackOverflow is not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not). For example, [Why "What Stack Overflow is Not" was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted) and [How can the "What Stack Overflow Is Not" post be improved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134986/how-can-the-what-stack-overflow-is-not-post-be-improved). Based on these posts I guess that Robert Harvey was the author of this post. When I look on posts for which he was awarded [Great question badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/great-question?userid=102937), I see that he was awarded one of them on Apr 19 '12, but instead of the link I see the text "post deleted or otherwise unavailable". It is possible that 10k+ users will see also link to the post there.

Of course, this is only a very limited experiment (I tried only two questions). It seems that the behavior is different depending whether I am able to see deleted posts on the given site. And I have only experimented with nice/good/great question badge. So from this we cannot say whether it works in the same way for other badges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the badge was awarded to you or you have the privilege to view deleted posts (10k or 2k/1k on public/private beta), you'll see the link to the deleted post. Otherwise, you'll get "post deleted or otherwise unavailable" (you could check that - just open an incognito tab).

This does work with any badges that are tied to a post id. So if you're not seeing neither link nor "post deleted or otherwise unavailable", you can be sure that nobody else could see the link, regardless of rep.

Note that "post deleted or otherwise unavailable" would also appear, for example, if there's a bug in the badge-awarding engine, [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/909391), so unless you have 10k or those are you badges, you wouldn't be able to distinguish actually unavailable post from a deleted one.