# Are proposals that are heavily downvoted ever get put under review and/or put into effect?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

If a proposal is downvoted heavily in Meta Stack Exchange, does the fact that it was downvoted heavily stop it from ever happening?

Comment: The formal notification by Stack Exchange, Inc. that a [tag:feature-request] will never be implemented is the special tag [tag:status-declined]. Now, it is possible that in theory a feature which is extremely unpopular with the community (which is determined by he fact that it has a very negative net score) will still be implemented by SE, but it's unlikely. SE tends to follow the "community built" approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proposals like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131029/ban-what-have-you-tried-links-in-comments) are [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but are heavily downvoted. You can figure that out by clicking on the link to the tag, sorting by votes and going to the last page.

Proposals like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c) are [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) but are pretty popular and with many votes.

That said, those are rare instances and it's highly unlikely that a more recent unpopular proposal be implemented.

Comment: [this proposal (at MSO)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/839601 "Should we discourage leading +/-1 on comments?") is at -180 now and was implemented. They didn't mark it [meta-tag:status-completed] though, possibly because they think it was superceded by [this adjustment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283874/839601 "Remove the limitation that stops comments from starting with +1 or -1") with more respectable score