# Vim integration for editing/posting on Stack Exchange websites

Tags: feature-request

How practical would it be to have a Vim-engine running on Stack Exchange, so that a subset of Vim's features could be used for editing and posting *on the website itself*?

What are the greatest challenges for developing such a feature?

Comment: Not practical, see dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is indeed a duplicate. I can't justify the huge amount of downvotes on that dupe, however.

Comment: I can - people who don't want this feature, for the reasons given in comments and answers. By downvotes the users say "we don't want such a thing", and it helps the team decide sometimes. (Not always - e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131029/ban-what-have-you-tried-links-in-comments)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess the majority really dislikes the idea of a vim implemention on SE? lol. I rest my case.

Comment: Not really, I mean it is not "personal" against vim, more like they don't want to change the current behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I think your right. Only, I don't think that's the purpose of the downvote option. Raising arguments in the comments would be more helpful. The OP's question, in itself, is a valid feature request. Moreover, a thorough well structured answer written in an answer would be sufficient to ventilate an objection against the feature.

Comment: That's the purpose of downvotes on meta sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it is clear and useful. Clear because it's quite directly stated. Useful because it became clear from the answers that there's an insufficient support from the community. I may not grant it it's full point for research effort, but still; it wins on two of the three criteria for an *upvote*.