# What is a "Do it for me" question?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes

Negative associations with the phrase "do it for me" include

- when the question is somehow trivial, and it's just a matter of taking the time to do it, as in "[the answer to the question could be found in 5 minutes by simply searching on google or such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136210/please-do-this-for-me-questions)."
- when the asker of the question [is never quite satisfied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140166/what-to-do-if-the-question-is-too-do-it-for-me) with reasonable answers, and keeps asking for more.

What should be added-to or removed-from this list?

Full disclosure -- this question is motivated by responses to a [question of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744646/nonparametric-multinomial-regression-in-r).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with either of those, I'd say its when the OP hasn't tried to solve the problem before asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the term "do it for me" has nothing to do with the question's triviality/complexity nor the willingness of the author to accept reasonable answers.

The "do it for me" simply implies that the author has failed to demonstrate any attempts of their own to solve the problem and they're asking someone to do it for them. [Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744646/nonparametric-multinomial-regression-in-r) seems to qualify as such.

You could probably remedy this situation by including a code snippet of what you tried and describe why it failed to accomplish what you needed. But if you're looking for someone to write code for you, this is not the correct forum for that. We're here to help you write your own code, not write it for you.

Answer (score 9):

A "Do it for me" question is one in which a specification or request for work is given as the question, with no (visible) attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Questions fitting this description are likely to be closed under:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question
>   checklist

I think your full disclosure question fully fits this definition. In this case you appear to be offering payment in the form of a bounty for fulfilling this specification. This is not what bounties are for and does not change the minimum understanding of the problem requirement.

However, the commenter could have explained this a little more and simply writing "'Do it for me' question" was not helpful.

Comment: I don't think the referenced comment is very constructive.  He should have elaborated rather than just putting a "label" on the post via comment.  But seeing the commenter's other MSO posts, he appears to be on a mission to close bad bounty questions.

Comment: Completely agree it wasn't a great comment, I tried to make that clear in my answer. I'll look into making that more explicit