# Why is the Community user giving out bounties?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, community-user

I clicked on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23628/158605) and see it has a bounty being offered by the Community User

[image]

<strike>I'm fairly positive this said "Pekka" last Friday, so what changed?</strike> Ignore this, apparently my memory is worse than I thought it was

Comment: Pekka changed his name?

Comment: @Servy He's not a moderator though, and if I scroll down he has one of the answers there and his name is the same (I checked to be sure he didn't delete his account)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm pretty sure Pekka doesn't have a diamond.

Comment: @Servy Community is reserved, also it's bot mod.

Comment: Does that mean somebody else is paying for my bounties now? Sweet. Brb (Seriously though, that is not my bounty)

Answer (score 10):

The user who offered the bounty was later removed, in this case Community takes over the bounty and handles the awarding.  It was not offered by Pekka originally.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. For some reason I was sure it was Pekka but I must be thinking of some other bounty of his.

Comment: Aww, did he leave over the discussion about civility? That would be too bad. I guess we'll never know

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, if I recall correctly that user had one of his questions on a similar topic downvoted fairly significantly. Would be a shame if he left because of that.

Comment: What does "handles the awarding." mean? Does it just fall back to the normal algorithm that applies when the bounty is not awarded to anyone?

Comment: @MartinSmith - correct