# Which links count toward the New User Restriction limit?

Tags: feature-request, spam

As a new user there is a 2 link limit for me to post in my questions or answers. My guess is the policy is probably to discourage spam from someone that read "*10 hottest seo spammer tricks of 2003 google doesn't want you to know*" or some similar awesomeness.

I also noticed that links to other questions and answers don't seem to count. Are there other 'safe' or whitelisted sites that we can reference?

Is there any chance the admins will expand this list?

For a lot of Stack Overflow questions and answers, this isn't enough for any kind of real thorough treatment of a topic. Maybe the quick rtfm link and a plunkr link.

Comment: It should be any link that is external to Stack Exchange counts.

Comment: You only need 10 reputation to get past the [New User limits](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Comment: Please note that RTFM posts or comments are not welcome on Stack Overflow: [How should we deal with RTFM comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/how-should-we-deal-with-rtfm-comments)

Comment: @JDB noted. They do seem to show up more times than not, all the same. To be more specific, my reason for including the obvious documentation in the question was to preempt those types of links in the answers.

Comment: Your links are now linkable. As Kate said if someone sees your post they may update it.

Comment: I believe links to any Stack Exchange site are allowed, only external links are limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to include more links in a good answer than 2, add them as plain text. Higher rep users may fix them for you, or you may be able to go back and fix them later.

That said, it would be highly unusual for someone's first good answer (once you've had an upvote you can post links) to need more than two links. A quick rtfm link is rarely actually useful. If the user has the comma in the wrong place, tell them that - don't give them a link to a page where they can discover their error. And if you're sure you know their mistake, you don't need to prove it by linking to something that says you're right.

Stack Overflow is not set up for "a real thorough treatment of a topic", by the way. And especially not by people who don't participate yet and haven't shown they know the norms. It's for answering questions, highly specific questions with highly specific answers.