# What is the policy on profanity on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, profanity

I recently answered a "humour +offtopic" CW question about annoying habits of colleagues with what I thought was a *most* amusing (and meant to be light-hearted) reply containing the word **--redacted--**. It got edited so the "profanity" was removed.

Was I inappropriate? Last time I checked, SO wasn't a my little pony appreciation society. It's hardly like I used the word [EXPLETIVE DELETED], is it?

Comment: The Unpredictable God has spoken: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-in-comments