# Question with answers deleted without discussion after like 20 minutes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, ethics

I've responded to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493697/algorithm-with-time-constraints/7496341) (the link is for 10k users; [the cached version before removal is here](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ettel5535/pub/so_deleted_question_on_R/computer_specs_for_r)), and put quite some effort into my answer that received 2 votes. I wanted to look at it again and, saw that the question was deleted, from my answers list, from my activity and reputation history.

Everything was deleted in such a short time!
You might argue that the question was put wrong, but I tried to handle it in the answer, and I tried to lead the OP. And the question with all answers was deleted **without any discussion**. This means I wasted my time completely and it won't help anyone.

I don't think this is a good way to motivate people to answer questions on Stack Overflow.

**Update after Jeff's answer:** I found the question quite straightforward and complete enough to formulate my answer and lead the OP. And I think it could help the OP. If this is not the purpose of the site, just correct me. I think the one who responds is the one to define whether the question was specific enough or not. (Moreover, there were similar questions like this one in the past, so I think it is useful also for others, and not too localized.)

Comment: As an aside, "WITH NO TRACES" isn't entirely true. Any user with at least 10k rep can see any deleted posts and these posts are not actually removed from the database - it's just that those of us with less than 10k can't see them at the moment.

Comment: also, answering such poorly asked questions teaches people they can do no work to ask a good, complete question and get a great answer. This is a very bad thing to encourage.

Comment: The Page-Not-Found-Page clearly states `This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation.`. If it was removed *without a trace* it would just state that page could not be found.

Comment: @Padded, DMA57, ok, I changed the title.

Comment: @padded also, that "question was removed" message links explicitly to http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Comment: @JeffAtwood: "Atwood!  What is best in life?"

Comment: Also a similar question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654967/r-in-a-netbook-system-requirements-for-using-r

Answer (score 19):

> I want to write an algorithm that will do a number of steps, but if the timer reaches a certain hour, the program must stop running.
>
> Could you show me how to do that? I am not sure where or how to place such a timer control.

This is the complete text of the "question", after 7 hours. Oh, and it has exactly one tag: [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm). No language, no nothing.

You should avoid answering questions that are so obviously incomplete -- they are always at risk of removal. Furthermore, answering such poorly asked questions teaches people they can do no work to ask a good, complete question and get a great answer. This is a very bad thing to encourage.

At most you should leave a comment prodding the OP to improve their question.

Comment: So...we're now calling these questions "incomplete"?

Comment: I would prefer to just Close the question, but good point about teaching a lesson.

Comment: @Jeff, I found the question quite straightforward and complete enough to formulate my answer and lead the OP. And I think it could help the OP. If this is not the purpose of the site, just correct me. I think the responder is the one to define whether the question was specific enough or not. (Moreover, there were similar questions like this one in the past, so I think it is useful also for others - and not too localized).

Comment: @tomas my deletion should tell you the answer to your question. If you want to help, *leave a comment encouraging the OP ask a better question in the first place*.

Comment: @PaddedCell, yes. Probably because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites) :)

Comment: Re *"At most"*: Do you mean *"At least"*?