# How do I report unwanted comments that contain offensive words?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are expletives allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)

I saw a comment that contained offensive words (e.g., fu**er).

How do I report that? Is this acceptable behavior on Stack Overflow?

Comment: When you have a question about a specific question/answer/comment then you would normally post a link to the item in question, this helps illustrate your question and can get it dealt with very quickly.

Comment: Are you Willing to see the Post Comment. Can I post The link here?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hover over the area next to the comment (where you would normally vote it up), and there is a flag icon to notify a moderator about it.

[image]

As to whether that is acceptable, I would say no, it's offensive language.  More so if it's directed at someone in particular.  People may have differing opinions on certain words, it's subjective.

Also, a link (or a screenshot) might help so others can check it out.  Right now, it's hearsay.

Comment: What I do I flag the Question or Remove the Word?

Comment: You flag the comment.

Comment: @Sagotharan Yes, sorry, I erased the content of the comment in the picture so it wouldn't distract from the illustration.

Comment: It's a shame i just notice it, even though i already up voted many good comments (@_@)