# What is the meaning of inappropriate content?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, inappropriate-content

I got this message while chatting on Stack Overflow:

> This user has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for ** minutes.

When I click on that link it is supposed to show inappropriate content that I have posted.
But I can't seem to view that contents.
Anyone care to explain how I can proceed with this? 
How does SO define inappropriate content?

Comment: If someone can get into trouble at work because they are reading that content, it is inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
can u provide an example please ? OR at least show which messages are inappropriate so that I can take care of that..

Comment: Are you joking? If it is inappropriate in chat, it is inappropriate here.

Comment: please view edited comments.

Comment: You might have posted link to "blacklisted" site. Can't find any official list though.

Comment: @programmer_1 Generally, anything under the ["Content Policy" of the terms of use for Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).  Admittedly, that can be a bit of a grey area sometimes, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Inappropriate content is codified in the [Content Policy for Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).

Moderators use this as the base set of guidelines *anywhere* on a Stack Exchange site (main site, meta, chat) to judge inappropriate content.

Additionally, there is a [section of the FAQ dedicated to the use of expletives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites).

Generally though, it's pretty obvious when you see it.  There's generally no need to show it/host it somewhere else, as most of the infractions are pretty egregious.

Of course, there are some areas which are rather grey, and we have to make judgement calls.  In these cases we'll collaborate with other moderators, or Stack Exchange staff, if necessary.

Comment: leapfrog___  :-D

Comment: @AdamRackis What, now you care?  I thought you were "retiring".  Don't you have that new job yet?  Time to raise some retag requests or something.

Comment: huh, didn't get notified on this comment.  Maybe Jeff is angry at all this banter and called in a favor.  Anyway, I start the job next Thurs., and like I said, I'm not retired, I'm just Professor Emeritus.  I'll drop by to teach an [interesting course](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129814/what-should-be-done-about-a-user-who-makes-a-threat/129816#129816) now and then, but for the most part I'll leave the hard work to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Only moderators can see deleted messages from other users in chat. You should be able to see your own deleted content though, I did a quick test to confirm that.

The suspension is automated, it happens when a successful spam/offensive flag is cast on a user's message. This means either 6 10k rep users or 1 moderator need to declare that flag as valid.

The usual reasons for those flags are profanity or insults to other users. Those are the most common reasons I've encountered so far.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.. I respect the policies defined by SO. But as I said earlier, it would be best if I would be able to view those contents, some how in my mail box etc.. So that I can at least know that.. However thanks again..

Comment: You should be able to see the message you were suspended for, it's likely a bug if you can't access it.