# Should we "enrich" or "pimp" Scala libraries?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

So, apparently there's a Scala design pattern called ["pimping" a library](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+pimp+my+library) by some and ["enriching" a library](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+enrich+my+library) by others, but mainly Stack Overflow.

It therefore follows that the tag chosen to represent the design pattern on Stack Overflow is [enrich-my-library](/questions/tagged/enrich-my-library).

The popular question "[How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5332801/168868)" has been subject to a minor tag war, where someone wants to revive [pimp-my-library](/questions/tagged/pimp-my-library) as a thing.  <sub><sup>(Yay, a tag war that isn't my fault!)</sup></sub>

Ignoring the, uh, *implications* of the word "pimp" here, which wording does the Scala community *want* to use and standardize on?

Comment: Maybe they should be synonyms?

Comment: *[obligatory "Yo, Dawg" reference]*

Comment: [Are expletives allowed on SE sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)

Comment: Is "pimp" an expletive to begin with?

Comment: I'd rather leave `pimps` for Travel SE or Cultural Exchange SE. Scala folks are IMNSHO rather immature to use the word. The same goes for the developers of Gimp. Mind you, there are [52 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck) on bf at SO.

Comment: +1 for not causing tag war

Comment: It's hard to imagine either of these tags having any utility.  Is anyone really going to look in [tag:pimp-my-library] or [tag:enrich-my-library] for a solution to his problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, with [29k Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+%22pimp+my+library%22+-site:stackoverflow.com), apparently yes, they are indeed going to look for "pimp my library" as an actual thing.

Comment: @Charles: I can probably get more search results for my dog.  Since when was the number of search results in Google considered a viable metric for creating a tag on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It isn't.  But so far there are 25ish questions that have been `encirch`ed out of 16k Scala questions.  It looks like someone edited out the `pimp` tag from the question that caused me to ask this, so it's kind of a moot point at the moment...