# Why was the CoC page changed to remove Jeff Atwood's original one?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, code-of-conduct

Why was the [Code of Conduct page](https://ham.stackexchange.com/conduct) changed last month?

**It used to have a excellent CoC written by the SE co-founder Jeff Atwood himself**, *and that is why I am an SE member and moderator*.

Am I missing something? If not, was there a public discussion about this (links, please.)?

---

Here is a partial excerpt:

> *Unacceptable Behavior*
>
> *No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.* Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.
>
> *No name-calling or personal attacks*. Focus on the content, not the
>   person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”).
>
> *No bigotry*. We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.
>
> *No harassment*. This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying,
>   intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually
>   suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.
>
> *Enforcement*
>
> We take your reports seriously. Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team. This is how moderators generally handle misconduct:
>
> *1. Warning*
>
> For most first-time misconduct, moderators will remove offending content and send a warning. Most issues are resolved here.
>
> *2. Account Suspension*
>
> For repetitive misconduct or behavior containing harassment, bigotry, or abuse, moderators will impose a temporary suspension (one day or more, depending on the violation).
>
> *3. Account Expulsion*
>
> For very rare cases, moderators will expel people who display a pattern of harmful destructive behavior toward our community.
>
> All actions will be taken on a case-by-case basis at the discretion of our moderators. ...
>
> We created this Code of Conduct because it reinforces the respect that we, as a community, expect from one another. Having a code also provides us with clear avenues to correct our culture should it stray off-course.

---

**What is missing --apparently-- is the specific prohibition against Vulgar Language**. (I should have explained that, sorry.)

Comment: What makes you think the CoC up last month was written by Jeff himself or was in any way original to the site? See  [The NEW new "Be Nice" Policy ("Code of Conduct") — Updated with your feedback](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839) and [The second draft of our Code of Conduct is available for feedback and review](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850) for actual history on it.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Okay, [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/358799) has that prohibition.

Answer (score 25):

That page didn't exist until just over a year ago: [Get to Know Our New Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/)

You may be thinking of the FAQ, which lived for a long time at /faq and then was broken up into separate pages under the Help Center - the relevant page there is [/help/behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

You can still read [the original FAQ in all its glory](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/stackoverflow.com/faq) via Archive.org.

Comment: Also worth noting the COC was drafted right here in consultation with the community

Comment: That’s a blast from the past